# How to solve this trig problem involving tangent?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\begin{cases} \alpha,\ \beta\in\bigl(0;\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)\\(\tan(\alpha)+1)(\tan(\beta)+1)=2\end{cases},$ find the value of $3.2\Bigl(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\pi}\Bigr)^2$

This problem was included in exercises on addition and subtraction of trig functions. I have multiplied the 2 expressions in the parantheses, then did other actions on it, but couldn't see where the addition formula for tan could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the addition formula for tangent is
$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}.$$

Now, if you multiply out the left-hand side of the given condition and subtract $1$ from both sides, you'll get
$$\tan\alpha\tan\beta+\tan\alpha+\tan\beta=1,$$
therefore
$$\quad \tan\alpha+\tan\beta=1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=1.$$
So we know that $\tan(\alpha+\beta)=1$ and $\alpha+\beta\in\left(0,\pi\right)$ due to the first condition. That completely determines the value of $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: I exactly did so, and got $\alpha+\beta=45^\circ$ and substituted it into $3.2\Bigl(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\pi}\Bigr)^2$ and got $3.2(\frac{\pi^2}{4})^2.$ Here $\pi$ remains, and the answer, according to the book is $0.3$. I can't get it.

Comment: @Tug'tekin: Your $\alpha+\beta$ is correct, but forget degrees. What is it in radians?

Comment: $3.2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\pi}\right)^2 = 
3.2\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)^2
=\dfrac{3.2}{16} = 0.2$

Comment: @zipirovich Did you mean "What is it in degrees?"

Comment: @Tug'tekin: No, I meant exactly what I said.

Comment: @Tug'tekin: Oh, now I see your mistake. If you divide $\pi/4$ by $\pi$, how did you end up with $\pi^2$ in the result?

Comment: @zipirovich from steven gregory's comment I found my mistake: I wrote the expression $\frac{\pi/4}{4}$ as $\frac{\pi}{4}:\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$ If I hadn't done so, I would have got the answer!